# What are the unknown steps to show $\mathbf{F}=-\nabla\psi$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, physics

**Given:** $\mathbf{F}=F(r)\ \mathbf{\hat{r}}$ is a spherically symmetric radial vector field which is continuous everywhere except at origin.

**To prove:** $\mathbf{F}=-\nabla \psi$

**Proof:**

\begin{align}
\mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{r}}&=F(r)\ \mathbf{\hat{r}} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{r}}=F(r)=\dfrac{d(\int F\ dr)}{dr}\\ &=\dfrac{d\psi}{dr}=\nabla \psi \cdot \mathbf{\hat{r}}
\end{align}

From here we *cannot* straight away deduce that: $\mathbf{F}=\nabla\psi$

***UNKNOWN STEPS ???***

$$\mathbf{F}=-\nabla\psi$$

$\mathbf{F}$ is conservative.

> **Question:** From what steps (unknown to me) can we get $\mathbf{F}=-\nabla\psi\ $?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You have a statement to prove, and then a proof of that statement. What is the first thing in the proof that do you not understand?

Comment: I have proved $$\mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{r}}=\nabla \psi \cdot \mathbf{\hat{r}}$$ From here on, how shall we deduce that $\mathbf{F}=-\nabla\psi$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's write 
$$
\newcommand{\rr}{{\mathbf{\hat{r}}}}
\newcommand{\th}{{\mathbf{\hat{\theta}}}}
\newcommand{\FF}{{\mathbf{F}}}
\FF(r, \theta) = F(r) \rr + 0 \th
$$
And define 
$$
\psi(r, \theta) = -\int_0^r F(t) ~ dt
$$
Then we have
\begin{align}
\frac{d\psi}{dr}(r, \theta) &= -F(r)\\
\frac{d \psi}{d\theta}(r, \theta) &= 0\\
\nabla \psi (r, \theta) 
&= \frac{1}{r} \frac{d \psi}{d\theta} \th  + \frac{d \psi}{dr}\rr\\
&= \frac{1}{r} 0 ~ \th  + -F(r)\rr\\
&= -F(r)\rr \tag{*}\\
\end{align}
so that $\nabla \psi$ is **again a radial vector field.** Two radial vector fields are equal if the coefficient of $\rr$ is the same in each.

As you observe,
\begin{align}
\FF(r, \theta) \cdot \rr 
&= F(r) \rr  \cdot \rr \\
&= F(r) \\
&= -\frac{d\psi}{dr} (r, \theta) \\
&= -\nabla \psi (r, \theta) \cdot \rr
\end{align}

Alternatively, you could just look at equation (*) and compare it to the definition of $\FF$ and see that $\FF = -\nabla \psi$.

**Summary:**

1. You needed to include a minus-sign in the definition of $\psi$ to get the answer you were asked for.
2. You needed to make the observation that the gradient of $\psi$ was a *radial* field, and then the computation you did would suffice.

Comment: Seems to me as an excellent answer with almost all needed details. The presentation is also attractive. However one thing which bothers me is the definition of potential. The Riemann integral is from $0$ to $r$ but the spherically symmetric radial vector field is not defined at origin. So it seems to me that it is inappropriate to take the Riemann integral from $0$ to $r$. Am I missing anything?

Comment: A radially-symmetric vector field -- if it's *truly* radially symmetric -- must be zero at the origin, for if we rotate the domain, the field-value must rotate by the same amount to get the field value at the new point (i.e. $F(r, \theta + \alpha) = R_\alpha(F(r, \theta)$). Since rotating the origin leaves the origin fixed, the vector field at the origin must be a vector unchanged by any rotation, i.e., the zero vector. But if you want, instead, to integrate from some other $r$ value, by all means do so. The difference in the thing you call the "potential" will just be a constant.

Answer (score 1):

You have a differential 
equation 
here in $-\operatorname{grad}\psi=\mathbf F=f(\mathbf r) \frac{\bf r}{\|\mathbf r\|}$, where $f$ is a scalar function and $\mathbf F$ a vector function.

One way to solve it for $\psi$ is by guessing a solution and then checking if its right.

By definition :

$$\mathbf r\cdot\operatorname{grad}\psi=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\psi(\mathbf x+t\mathbf r)-\psi(\mathbf x)}t$$

where $t$ is a scalar and $\mathbf x, \mathbf r$ vectors.

From this follows :

$$\operatorname{grad}(\|\mathbf r\|)=\frac{\mathbf r}{\|\mathbf r\|}$$

And chain rule :

$$\operatorname{grad}(f(g(\mathbf r)))=\frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dg}\operatorname{grad}(g)$$

Now guessing $\psi(\mathbf r)=-\left(\int f(\mathbf r)\,\mathrm d\|\mathbf r\|\right)\cdot\|\mathbf r\|$

we get $-\operatorname{grad}\psi=f(\mathbf r)\frac{\mathbf r}{\|\mathbf r\|}$ so this is the right solution to the differential equation.

Comment: I took the liberty of TeX-ifying your solution; please look it over to see if I missed anything

Comment: Thanks nice, but now looking at it I think there is an inherent flaw at least of syntacticall nature.. Meaning I thing i can't exactly write it down like I did

Comment: I tried to make up a function y(g) =∫ f dg, and g (r) =|r|, I don't know if this works. This is what you missed and instead put a dot product. But I don't know if it's right anyway.

Comment: I i probably should have put 2 more lines in to prove grad abs(r)